# Creating an OS level toast in Tizen

Tags: toast, tizen

I am trying to create a `Toast` in a `Tizen` app. The Toast will be running outside context of my app. However, I am not able to find any example which works yet.

Here is what all i have tried so far:

```
function toastAlert(msg) {
  $('#popupToastMsg').empty();
  $('#popupToastMsg').append(msg);
  $('#popupToast').fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#popupToast').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 2000);
  console.log(msg);
}

function sendAlert() {
  toastAlert('ToastWorks');
}
```

The above code generates in app message not a toast. Even https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=tizen+toast&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93 does not help much. Can anyone suggest a better approach and a way to do same.

Comment: 1. What is OS level toast?
2. Are you including any js library to generate the toast?

You can follow this link to know more about how to implement toast popup in web apps https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/wearable/widgets/widget_popup.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can't make popup like toast out of your web application.

Current Tizen web application don't support it.

but I think maybe you can use [notification api](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/notification.html) for your job.